# Symfony3 Advanced search engine

Tags: symfony, search, repository, search-engine

Hy,

I try to make a search engine for my web site, but in 2 different entity. In the first I'm looking for the 'ville' and in the second the 'matiere' and I want the idtutor who match!

My controller:

```
public function resultat($ville, $matiere)
    {
        $info = array();

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $repository = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:tutor1');
        $listAdverts = $repository->findBy(array('ville' => $ville));

        foreach ($listAdverts as $advert) {
            $advert->getIdTutor();

            $repository = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:matiere');
            $listAdverts = $repository->findBy(array('matiere' => $matiere, 'id_tutor' => $advert->getIdTutor()));

            foreach ($listAdverts as $advert) {

                $idtutor = $advert->getIdTutor();

                $repository = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User');
                $info1 = $repository->findBy(array('id' => $idtutor));

                $repository2 = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:tutor2');
                $info2 = $repository2->findBy(array('id_tutor' => $idtutor));

                $info = array(
                    'info1' => $info1,
                    'info2' => $info2);
            }

        }

        return $this->render('/rechercher-un-tuteur.html.twig', $info);
    }
```

and for the front, my twig:

```
            {% if info1|length > 0 %}

                {% for tutor in info1 %}
                    <h5> prénom : {{ tutor.FirstName }} </h5>

                            {% for tutor2 in info2 %}
                            <p> {{ tutor2.PresentationTutor }} </p>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}

            {% else %}

                <li>Pas (encore !) de Tuteur</li>
            {% endif %}
```

But I have just the last tutor that appears... Have you some idea?
thinks

Comment: You are overriding your `$info` array within your foreach loop, so only the Tutor that was processed last will be saved there

Comment: I had try a solution like : $info[$i] and $i++ but it's not working...

Comment: did you put `$info = array()` outside of your foreach loop? is there any error thrown? Try enabling php notices aswell.

Comment: yes I have put it! I'm despair!!

Comment: up please?? I haven't more idea...